# Flask - Templates, Routes and HTML

Tags: flask

I'm in the process of designing a webapp using Flask and have begun with creating a template to base my other pages on.

For my navigation bar, I was wanting to have a coloured indicator on the button for the currently selected page. Is there any way in Flask template to have a sort of :

```html
{% if "route == '/'": %}
  <a class="navbar-item has-background-primary" href='/'> Home </a>
{% else: %}
   <a class="navbar-item" href='/'> Home </a>
{% endif %}
```

I was hoping to reduce the amount of times I use this code, and actually make use of the template function, rather than have code for the navigation bar in every page I will design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by doing passing variables through the routes, such as 'is_home' set to a random value ('yes'). Then, if the variable is defined - display the button with the background (as it will be on that view/route), else show the blank button.

```
@app.route('/downloads')
def download_links():
    return render_template('download.html', is_downloads='Yes')
```

```html
    <div id="navigationBar" class="navbar-menu">
              <div class="navbar-start">
               
               
                {% if is_home is not defined %}
                
                <a class="navbar-item" href='/'>
                {% else %}
                <a class="navbar-item has-background-success-light" href='/'>
                
                {% endif %}

                Home
              </a>
              {% if is_downloads is not defined %}
              <a class="navbar-item" href='/download'>
            
              {% else %}
              <a class="navbar-item has-background-success-light" href='/download'>
              {% endif %}
          
                  Downloads
                </a>
          
            </div>
```